# Error "Too many active jobs" printing via the cupsPrintFile function

Tags: c, linux, printing, cups

In C code under Linux I use libcups to make printouts in a code like :

```
int job_id = cupsPrintFile(printerName, tmpFileNameCopiaVettore, addToprinterTitle, cupsOptionCopiaVettore.num_options, cupsOptionCopiaVettore.options);
if (job_id == 0) {
            printf("Error ***** %s (printerName <%s>)\n", cupsLastErrorString(), printerName);
}
```

If I send a large number of prints I get the error "Too many active jobs", how can i manage it within my code ?

Comment: Your choices seem to be to queue it or drop it. You could also send an alert to the sysadmin.

Comment: My interest is how to handle it at the C code level, I would like to know if I can intercept the error code, or know how many jobs are in the print spooler and act accordingly

Comment: https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.2.0/LSB-Printing/LSB-Printing/libcups.cupsgetjobs.1.html